# How to load a big sparse tensor in scikit-tensor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to do tensor analysis with python using scikit-tensor.

```
https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor
```

However, there is few docs about it.
I'd like to read a big tensor from files. I cannot find out what the function in it i should use.
Or is there any more easy tensor tools for python?

Comment: What kind of tensor model do you need? For DTI, HARDI, DSI?

Comment: a simple term-document-language tensor. I'd like to do PARAFAC decomposition on it.